# Using SVG Icons

Tags: css, svg

I'm using use my own SVG icons and I'm trying to find the best way of using them.

I would like to keep the color but also adjust it if needed to match a theme or on when using hover.

I have tried using the following script which changes the following into an embedded SVG but as I load my scripts at the bottom of my HTML doc, I get a horrible jumping effect.

```js
$(function(){
jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
        var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

        // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
        }
        // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
        }

        // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

        // Check if the viewport is set, else we gonna set it if we can.
        if(!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
            $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
        }

        // Replace image with new SVG
        $img.replaceWith($svg);

    }, 'xml');

});
});
```

```css
svg {width: 350px; height: 350px;}
svg path {fill: #000 !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Windows_logo_-_2012_%28red%29.svg" alt="Microsoft" width="350" />
```

I've then tried to embed the the SVG by copying the code from Illustrator but the only way I can edit the colours is if I delete them in the html doc as my css won't override them.

What is the best way while keeping them from jumping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go down the embedded route (which is my preferred option) - you don't actually need the majority of the HTML that Illustrator usually throws out.

Here is an example of your SVG with the most minimal code, then you can just use CSS to change the colours how you wish :-)

```css
svg {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}

svg path {
  fill: #000;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(3)
}

#svg3 path {
fill: turquoise;
}

#svg3:hover path {
fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg2">
  <path d="m0,12.402,35.687-4.8602,0.0156,34.423-35.67,0.20313zm35.67,33.529,0.0277,34.453-35.67-4.9041-0.002-29.78zm4.3261-39.025,47.318-6.906,0,41.527-47.318,0.37565zm47.329,39.349-0.0111,41.34-47.318-6.6784-0.0663-34.739z" id="path4"/>
</svg>


<!-- Another exmaple below using CSS to change the colours -->
<svg id="svg3">
  <path d="m0,12.402,35.687-4.8602,0.0156,34.423-35.67,0.20313zm35.67,33.529,0.0277,34.453-35.67-4.9041-0.002-29.78zm4.3261-39.025,47.318-6.906,0,41.527-47.318,0.37565zm47.329,39.349-0.0111,41.34-47.318-6.6784-0.0663-34.739z" id="path4"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline SVGs would be best IMO.

Export your SVGs using Illustrator (if you have troubles, follow this [excellent guide](https://medium.com/@colinlord/how-to-export-svgs-for-the-web-from-illustrator-829bc1c841f6) by Colin Lord).

Then remove the colors from your SVG code and set them only using CSS.
If you have trouble overriding your colors you can give your SVGs IDs for more specifity.